# ElasticSearch : 'IN' and 'AND' operators

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to achieve the following SQL equivalent in Elastic search:

```
SELECT LEVEL, @TIMESTAMP, MESSAGE FROM INDEX_1 WHERE LEVEL IN ['LOW','HIGH'] 
AND @TIMESTAMP > sometime ORDER BY @TIMESTAMP
```

My try :

```
{  "_source":["LEVEL", "@TIMESTAMP", "MESSAGE"],
"sort" : [{ "@timestamp" : "asc" }],
"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"terms" : {
          "level" : ["INFO","DEBUG"]},
{"range": { "@timestamp":{ "gt":time}}}]}}}
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great start! There are some missing curly braces, level values are different and some field names must be lowercased. Try this:

```
{
  "_source": [
    "level",
    "@timestamp",
    "message"
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": "asc"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "level.keyword": [
              "LOW",
              "HIGH"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gt": time
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Val. No luck.

Comment: And that means? Can you tell what you get vs what you expect?

Comment: What I got is :{'took': 0, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 0, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}}

Comment: {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "level": "HIGH"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": { "@timestamp":{ "gt":time}}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}  - This query fetches me result.

Comment: See my updated answer. The problem with `match` is that you cannot test several values (i.e. `IN` semantics)